# how can I division bootstrap container for background color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to division bootstrap container for change background. I don't want use row and col inside of container.

I attach an image for description.
[image]

Comment: can you use Css and Media quiries?

Comment: yes I can but plz look at to my image.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Which version of Bootstrap? Can you please clarify "I don't want use row and col inside of container", but the image shows row and col.

Comment: @ZimSystem I mean row and col are inside of container, but background color is out of container and I can not use col and row there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="left_side">
   <!-- Your content-->
</div>

<div class="right_side">
  <!-- Your content-->
</div>
```

in stylesheet

```
<style>
    body
     {
          width:100%;
      }
    .left_side,.right_side
          {
            width:50%;
            height:100px; /*Depends on your content make it as height:auto;*/
            float:left;
          }
    .left_side
         {
            background-color:gray;
          }
      .right_side
         {
            background-color:white;
          }
</style>
```

Here is the JSfiddle link   https://jsfiddle.net/no0Lz0o7/